# Circular includes due to enum within a class in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an interesting variant of the oft-repeated C++ circular include dilemma. In short: I want to use an enum that is defined in a subclass as the type of an instance variable in a parent class. Here's a minimal example:

**a.h**

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include "c.h"

class ClassA
{
public:
    ClassA() {};

    void setStatus(ClassC::Status status) { a_status = status; }
    void setA(int val) { a_var = val; }
    int valueA() { return a_var; }
    ClassC::Status status() { return a_status; }

private:
    int a_var;
    ClassC::Status a_status;
};

#endif // A_H
```

**c.h**

```
#ifndef C_H
#define C_H

#include "a.h"

class ClassC : public ClassA
{
public:
    enum Status
    {
        Valid,
        Invalid
    };

    ClassC(): ClassA() {};

    void setC(int val) { c_var = val; }
    int valueC() { return c_var; }

private:
    int c_var;
};

#endif // C_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "a.h"

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    ClassA *obj = new ClassA();
    return 0;
}
```

I can't forward declare the enum in `a.h` because the name of  the enum has to be simple, and ClassC::Status isn't. It's important that the enum be within the namespace of the child class, because there are *lots* of such classes, and I need to isolate the names of the enum items from values in other enumcs. Any ideas?

Comment: If it is important that the enum be defined within the child class, then it is important that the parent not have one of those enums :(

Comment: You really going to have `enum Status` declared with different body?

Comment: `ClassA : public Base` and `ClassC : public Base`, where Base has no data members,  but types and constants, only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In short: I want to use an enum that is defined in a subclass as the type of an instance variable in a parent class.

You cannot do that. You'll need to come up with a different mechanism.

Comment: I suspected that that was going to end up being the answer. Thanks.